# Simplifying using Taylor's expansion.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Let $u_n(a)=(1+\frac{a}{n})^n$

Using Taylor's expansion simplify : $Q=u_n(a+b)-u_n(a)u_n(b)$

I've tried this myself , but I wasn't able to succeed.

I've come to result that $Q=-\frac{ab}{2} +\frac{(n-1)(-ab^2-ba^2)}{2n}-(\frac{(n-1)(ab)}{2n})^2$ (having stopped at order 2 for $u_n(a+b),u_n(a),u_n(b)$ , hoping the following order would follow by induction)

My result is most likely wrong since it made the form more complicated than simplified.

If anyone could help i would be grateful!

Comment: daily reminder that Taylor has the big Ts

Comment: Are $a$ and $b$ $\approx 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$u_n(a) = 1 + a + \frac {(n-1)}{2n}a^2 \cdots$

or

$u_n(a) = \sum_\limits{i=0}^{n} {n\choose i}(\frac {a}{n})^i$

$\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} u_n(a) = e^a$

and $\lim_\limits{n\to \infty} u_n(a+b) - u_n(a)u_n(b) = 0$

If we are just looking at the order 2 expression....

$u_n(a+b) = $$1 + a+b + {n\choose 2}\frac {a^2 + 2ab + b^2}{n^2}\\
1 + a+b + {n\choose 2}\frac {a^2}{n^2} + {n\choose 2}\frac {b^2}{n^2} + \frac {n-1}{n}ab\\
1 + a+b + {n\choose 2}\frac {a^2}{n^2} + {n\choose 2}\frac {b^2}{n^2} + ab -\frac {1}{n}ab\\$

$u_n(a)u_n(b) = $$(1+a+{n\choose 2} \frac {a^2}{n^2})(1+b + {n\choose 2} \frac {b^2}{n^2})\\ 1 + a + b + {n\choose 2}\frac{a^2}{n^2} + {n\choose 2}\frac{b^2}{n^2} + ab$

When we multiply this out we are ignoring the 3rd and 4th order terms.  If we want to pick them up later we can.

$u_n(a+b) - u_n(a)u_n(b) = -\frac {1}{n}ab$

The third order terms:

${n\choose3}\frac {3a^2b + 3ab^2}{n^3} - {n\choose 2}\frac{a^2b + ab^2}{n^2}\\
\frac {-2n + 2}{n^2} (a^2b + ab^2)$

Comment: in $u_n(a+b)$ is there no ${n\choose 2}\frac {b^2}{n^2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem
(which is a special case
of Taylor's theorem).

$u_n(a)
=(1+\frac{a}{n})^n
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{a^k}{n^k}
$.

So

$\begin{array}\\
u_n(b)u_n(a)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{b^k}{n^k}\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\frac{a^j}{n^j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j}\frac{a^j}{n^j}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{b^k}{n^k}\\
\end{array}
$

and

$\begin{array}\\
u_n(a+b)
&=(1+\frac{a+b}{n})^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac{(a+b)^k}{n^k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}a^jb^{k-j}
\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=j}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^k}\binom{k}{j}a^jb^{k-j}
\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^na^j\sum_{k=j}^n \binom{n}{k}\frac1{n^k}\binom{k}{j}b^{k-j}
\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^na^j\sum_{k=j}^n \dfrac{n!k!}{n^kk!(n-k)!j!(k-j)!}b^{k-j}
\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{n!a^j}{j!}\sum_{k=j}^n \dfrac{k!}{n^kk!(n-k)!(k-j)!}b^{k-j}
\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{n!a^j}{j!(n-j)!}\sum_{k=j}^n \dfrac{(n-j)!}{n^k(n-k)!(k-j)!}b^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\dfrac{n!a^j}{j!(n-j)!}\sum_{k=j}^n \binom{n-j}{k-j}\dfrac{1}{n^k}b^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}a^j\sum_{k=j}^n \binom{n-j}{k-j}\dfrac{1}{n^k}b^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}a^j\sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \binom{n-j}{k}\dfrac{1}{n^{k+j}}b^{k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}\dfrac{a^j}{n^j}\sum_{k=0}^{n-j} \binom{n-j}{k}\dfrac{b^k}{n^{k}}\\
\end{array}
$

Now work out the difference.